# Calculating a limit that tends towards negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

How would one go about calculating this limit?

$$\lim _{x\to -\infty }\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+14}+x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-2}+x}$$

I tried to substitute $x = -t$ to get something that tends towards $+\infty$, but I don't know how to calculate that limit that I get after substituting.

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ if $x<0$

Comment: Thanks, I think I calculated it using what you said. Is the limit 1?

Comment: Multiply by the conjugates of the numerator and denominator to get terms that don't go to 0.

Comment: Divide up and down by $x$, simplest way.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I still get 0/0 using your method. I tried that first. I may not be doing it correctly? I think I am

Comment: @Tavish Ended up with 1. It seems correct?

Comment: @DavidIlic Yes. ${}$

Comment: Thank you. That was very obvious, I was just overthinking it.

Comment: @Tavish That is incorrect, see David’s [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105217/calculating-a-limit-is-wolframalpha-wrong-or-am-i-wrong/4105236?noredirect=1#comment8486741_4105236)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh yes, right right.